# Paste multi-cursor copy/paste WITHOUT newlines in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Is there a way to paste a multi-cursor (`Ctrl+d`, `Ctrl+d`, ... `Ctrl+C`) select, stripped of its newlines?

If `[...]` represents the highlight, and `⦙` the cursor:

```
The ⦙[red].
The ⦙[blue].
The ⦙[green].
```

And if I pasted I'd get:

```
red
blue
green⦙
```

but instead I want

```
redbluegreen⦙
```

Is this possible?

Comment: try https://github.com/joshdavenport/PasteAsOneLine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the following script @:
`/Packages/Paste Without NewLines/paste_without_newlines.py`

```python
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class paste_without_newlines( sublime_plugin.TextCommand ):
    def run( self, edit ):

        clipboard = sublime.get_clipboard()
        clipboard = clipboard.replace( "\n", "" )
        sublime.set_clipboard( clipboard )
        self.view.run_command( "paste" )
```

---

To execute via `Command Palette > Paste Without NewLines`, add the following code @:
`/Packages/Paste Without NewLines/Default.sublime-commands`

```json
[
    {
        "caption": "Paste Without NewLines",
        "command": "paste_without_newlines",
    },
]
```

---

To execute via <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + Alt + V</kbd>, add the following code @:
`/Packages/Paste Without NewLines/Default.sublime-keymap`

```json
[
    {
        "keys": ["ctrl+shift+alt+v"],
        "command": "paste_without_newlines",
    },
]
```

Comment: The 2nd replace in the plugin `.replace( "\r", "" )` is not needed. Sublime Text always uses just `\n` to represent new lines internally, regardless of the OS and the current file's line ending setting. The line ending setting only comes into effect when saving files. See: [Is a newline always represented internally by ‘\n’?](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/is-a-newline-always-represented-internally-by-n/20506)

Comment: Also a `sublime_plugin.TextCommand` class name (as well as an `ApplicationCommand` but not a `EventListener`) should use *CamelCase* followed by the word `Command`. In this case `PasteWithoutNewlinesCommand` should be used instead of `paste_without_newlines` in the line `class paste_without_newlines...` . ST translates *CamelCaseCommand* class names into a ST *snake_name* command, i.e. `paste_without_newlines`, dropping the `Command` ending. To be fair the plugin works as is but the [plugins documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/plugins.html) is clear about this.

Comment: Just in case I wasn't clear the `PasteWithoutNewlinesCommand` plugin class name gets translated to the ST `paste_without_newlines` command so that is still what should still be used in the key binding and the command palette entry.

Comment: @mattst : Good call on `\r`, I didn't feel like looking it up & added it just in case. `a sublime_plugin class name should use CamelCase followed by the word Command` I disagree. You linked to the **unofficial** documentation, and the **official** documentation is known to be incomplete. I used to use `PluginNameCommand`, until I found some example that used `plugin_name`. IMO; it's a better option as it reflects the actual text that will be used in the command & it doesn't require the redundancy of the `Command` suffix. Also, there are no issues with using it since ST treats them the same.

Comment: As you wish but the same advice is given in several places in the unofficial docs [here](https://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/plugins.html) and [here](https://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/plugins.html) and the unofficial docs are linked from the [main ST support page](https://www.sublimetext.com/support). All the plugins in the `Default.sublime-package` archive use the `CamelCaseCommand` convention for classes that inherit `TextCommand`, `ApplicationCommand`, and `WindowCommand` but not `EventListener` derived classes, so maybe there's a reason why.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else stumbling across this, there's a sublime text package that solves this exact problem, it's called **Paste PDF Text Block**.

You can then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> the text you want to copy from a pdf file into a new file in Sublime Text.

Worked a treat, and is a good solution if you don't know enough about making your own packages in sublime text, like me :(